# IIS Url Rewrite maps from custom provider?

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

Is it possible to access a dictionary or something of a certain rewrite map from your rewrite custom provider?

Something like...{Provider:key,mapname}

which in code does something like {Mapname:key}

?

Answer (score 2):

When you inherit from IRewriteProvider, in your Initialize() method you will get a Dictionary with all the settings:

```
public void Initialize(IDictionary<string, string> settings, IRewriteContext rewriteContext)
{
    ...
}
```

which comes from the following config section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <providers>
      <provider name="MyCustomRewriteProvider" type="MyCustomRewriteProvider.....">
        <settings>
          <!--add key="keyName" value="keyValue" /-->
        </settings>
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </rewrite>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

You can refer to this article for detailed information on how to create a custom URL Rewrite provider:

- [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/)

Comment: but this was not the question?! the question was about rewrite maps in provider, not setting in provider?

Comment: Kateroh - Can you please help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506551/reading-a-cookie-value-using-url-rewrite-for-iis-wizard-unable-to-validate-at