# Reading cookie value : Using URL Rewrite Provider module - Unable to validate at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData

Tags: c#, iis, cookies, url-rewriting

I have requirement to append **USERNAME** to the URL in server side using URL Rewrite module.

**Why?**: 
I have website **site1**, when USER logs in to site1, he will see a link to **site2.**, This link is URL or reports. (Tableau). 
Authenticated ticket has been created using **FormAuthentication** in site1.
When **USER** clicks the link, authenticated **username** should be passed to site2.

I could append username from client side, but due to security issues I have to append username to URL in server side before it gets executed.

So I have decided to use URL rewrite provider, which grabs the **username** by decrypting the cookie value as shown below

```
     namespace PlatformAnalysisUrlProvider.PlatformAnalysisProvider
      {
       class AnalysisRewriteProvider: IRewriteProvider, IProviderDescriptor
       {
          public void Initialize(IDictionary<string, string> settings,
                                 IRewriteContext rewriteContext)
          {

          }

          public string Rewrite(string value)
          {
             string[] cookievalues = value.Spli('=');
             FormAuthentication ticket = FormAuthentication.Decrypt(cookievalues[1]);

              //Decrypt throws error as shown below
          } 
       }
      }
```

**Cookie Values**

```
        cookievalues [0] =  has the key

        cookievalues [1] =  has the value
```

Example:

```
        233AWJDKSHFHFDSHFJKDFDKJFHDKJFKDJFHDHFDHFKJHDFKJHDFJHDKJFHDSKJFHDF
```

It's a cookie value. But decrypt is not happening

I am getting following error

```
        Unable to validate data.
        at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(
        Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, 
        Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, 
        Boolean signData)
```

Here is my settings in IIS for URL Rewrite

- Requested URL: Matches the Patterns
- Using: Regular Expression
- Ignore Case - Checked
- Conditions - 
        Input   : {HTTP_COOKIE}
        Type    : Matches the Pattern
        Pattern : .*
- Action Type - Rewrite
- Rewrite URL - http://11.155.011.123{HTTP_URL}&USERNAME={PlatformAnalysisUrlProvider:{C:0}}

[I have also set up MACHINE KEY as suggested by this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035471/sharing-authentication-between-two-web-applications)

[I have referred this post for development](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module)

One of the stack overflow post suggested that it might be firewall or antivirus issue. But I do not have antivirus installed or firwall enabled.

It really helps if someone direct me to **code sample** where web site hosted in IIS and URL Rewrite provider is used.

**Updating Error Log**

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
Notification - "PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST"
HttpReason - "URL Rewrite Module Error"

**Updating post with Machine Key Info**

```
     <MachineKey Description="AES" validation="SHA1"
      descriptionKey="******"
      validationKey="******" CompatibilityMode="Framework20SP2">
```

**Reason May be** - The website where cookie getting created is developed using .NET Framework 4.5.  The provider where we reading the cookie is Framework 3.5. Is this may be the cause? OR Do we need config file for Provider project?

**Updates** - I have added machine key to Machine.config , but it still did not work :(

**Alternative Solution**

- Add App.config to class Library

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
   <appSettings>
   <!-- ... -->
      <add key="SecurityKey" value="somevalue"/>
   <!-- ... -->
   </appSettings>
   </configuration>
  ```
- Copy config to GAC
  Follow this blog - http://techphile.blogspot.in/2007/02/2.html
- Encrypt the value ([refer here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt)) and create custom cookie during Login
- Use the Decrption logic inside custom rewrite provider

Comment: I think you're trying to use a within-website encryption methodology in an unsupported way between two different websites. Consider instead having Website1 function as a facade, providing the authentication function as you do now. Requests on that website that contain the valid token can then be proxied forward to Website2. Website1 can decrypt the information needed for authentication, and then poke any information needed for identification on Website2 into the request headers prior to forwarding the request on to Website2. If that information must be encrypted, then encrypt it yourself ...

Comment: ... (not using the FormAuthentication object) in a way you can decrypt at Website2.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

The good thing about this is that the error is a general decryption error and not one with URL Rewrite itself, so that gives you a wider area to search for help. The mechanics of URL Rewrite seem to be right.

Decrypting means that it must be encrypted by the same method as you're decrypting it. So it has to be the right cookie and the right decryption method.

Since you're not checking which cookie that you're reading from, you could get unexpected results if the wrong cookie is first in the list of cookies.

Here are some steps that I recommend to troubleshoot this:

- Create a simple URL Rewrite rule that will give you the value of your cookie. I created a rule to do that in my example below. You can test it by going to yoursite.com/getcookie. It should redirect to yoursite.com/?Cookie={cookievalue}
- Then you can test your code outside of the URL Rewrite provider. You can create a simple console app or winforms app to test the rest of the code.
- I recommend adding a check for the existence of the cookie and then a check again for the 2nd value. For example: *if (cookievalues[1] != null)*.
- When developing the decryption method, you don't have to worry about URL Rewrite. As long as it works in a test app in .NET then you should be set.

```html
<rule name="Get cookie value" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^getcookie" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/?Cookie={HTTP_COOKIE}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks scott for steps, I am unable to debug the Provider code in Visual studio, break point is not hitting. Can you provide best practice to develop provider and debugging information, so it helps me to check if COOKIE value is passing or not.

Comment: one thing I observed:  My provider code is in .net framework version 2.0, if I change it to 4.5, "Managed Type" dropdown in Provider configuration screen of IIS will not display the values

Comment: Hi @Deepak. To debug with Visual Studio you can compile and deploy, and then manually attach the debugger to the IIS w3wp.exe worker process. That should let you know catch it in VS. Otherwise, you can create a stand-alone app for just the decryption and debug it separately. A simple testing app is likely easier to debug.